# Disable HTML Encoding on Asp.net HyperLink attributes

Tags: asp.net, html-encode

I have a HyperLink on my usercontrol in which I set the `onlick` event dynamically on the server side like this :

```
this.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("javascript:alert('{0}')", base.NavigateUrl);
```

The problem is that when Asp.net renders the page, it ends up with something like this

```
<a href='...' onclick="javascript:alert(&#39;TEST&#39;)>LINK</a>
```

which obviously is not valid Javascript. Using `"` instead of `'` wouldn't help neither, the generated HTML is `alert(&quot;TEST&quot;)`

Is there any way around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick="javascript:alert(&#39;TEST&#39;)"` is perfectly valid.  When the page is parsed, entities should be replaced with their counterparts before JavaScript processes the value.  So in pass 1, the HTML parser will change the attribute value to `javascript:alert('TEST');`, which is valid JavaScript.

Comment: Oh thanx, I've been inspecting the HTML directly

Answer (score 1):

It is not working when using Jquery.

Server side:

```
this.Attributes["onclick"] = "$('#button').click();";
```

Client side:

```
onclick="$(&amp;#39;#button&amp;#39;).click();" gives an error.
```

Is there anyway to just get 'real' single quotes client side?

Answer (score 0):

royu,

Unfortunately, Microsoft thinks this is a "security feature" and they don't really care about browser or JavaScript compatibility. One way to override it is to use Eval([string]) instead of the plain text. In that case the value should not be encoded.